# How to remove extra border when button is selected?

Tags: button, border, selected

I have few buttons in a stack panel and when I click the button I get an extra white border and it disappears only if I click any other button. I trayed to set focusable="false" but the border is still there when the button is in clicked state. I even trayed to set borderthickness to transparent and it didn't work. I'm using xaml.

thanks